# Install mongoose by npm in Windows

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I began to develop a project using `node.js` and `mongodb`.

To interact with the database, I need to install the package `mongoose`, but I have been having problems installing it.

Maybe someone already had a similar problem, and knows how to solve it.

I run command `npm install mongoose`

And get some errors

[image]

Comment: Apart from your specific problem, instead of installing each package you need manually, you should specify your dependencies within a `package.json` file, and then you do something like `npm install`. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) on how to create a `package.json` file.

Comment: Install python 2.7 - its required to build these binary type libraries in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CViejo, thanks for the link, where I found a lot of information on my topic.
Usually, this problem is solved by installing Python 2.7 + Visual studio 2010.
Иut in my case there were problems with the operating system, just could not understand that.
As a solution, I installed new Windows7(64) + Phyton 2.7.1 + Visual studio 2013 + nodeJS (x86).
and try  `npm install mongoose` - it work.

Thank you for help in my problem.